# Snakes and Ladders - Matlab help!

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a simulation for snakes and ladders in Matlab but I'm stuck.

How would I write something to check if the player is on a square that has a snake or ladder? I read somewhere that in Python you can just use something like "**if** newposition **in** snakes" (where snakes is an array of all the snake related moves), but I don't think the "**in**" command works in Matlab?

I was thinking I could just do "if newposition = 2, position=5" but I'm sure there's an easier way than making 100 **if** statements right...

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: **if** isladder[position] == 1 ... $\;\;$

Comment: I think @RickyDemer meant `if isladder(position) == 1`. Also, the commands `any`, `all`, and `isequal` may be helpful. And learn to combine [short-circuiting operators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/logical-operators.html#f0-39129) `&&` and `||` in single `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one suggestion: Have one array
SnakeHead = [15,17,93];
and another
SnakeTail = [5,6,88];
then during the game

b = find(newposition==SnakeHead);
if length(b)>0,
  position = SnakeTail(b);
end;